# Firebase 'observe' fires multiple times with different data

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database

I set an observer for some directory, represented as `ref` in this case like so (simplified code sample):

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { snap in
     if snap.exists(){
         let some = MyStructure(snap: snap)
         print(some.date)
     }
})
```

The problem is, even though the data in that location (`ref`) does never change, handler gets called multiple times (usually 2 times) and, what's bugging me most, with different data for just one field (the `date` one). Any thought on why this could be happening?

---

**P.S**. I usually remove all observers for a reference inside its callback handler, but, in this case, I can't do that, since the first call returns data with wrong `date` field, yet the next one tends to be the right one.

**P.S.S**. I cannot use '.observeSingleEvent' method, since it uses cached data (stored by Firebase, I believe), and here it is essential to retrieve only relevant data.

Comment: Are you using [disk caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence)? Because if so, the first event could be coming from the disk cache.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I do, yet, how come I get data with date set to 1970 when it is never the case?

Comment: That sounds like you have a location with a `0` value for a timestamp. Without seeing how you got into this situation, it's hard to say anytjing more than that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you of the lead with 'disk caching'. It must be faulty, since it kept values for those fields as those which they never were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason why

After some digging I've discovered that double-firing is an intended behaviour for Firebase SDK. First - cached snapshot for a reference, Second - retrieved from Realtime Database.

### How to handle

1. Set `isPersistenceEnabled` to `false`. This will ensure that all the `.observe` calls do not use data cached locally on the device
2. Update data with the second call (if there will be one)

Comment: How do you update data with the second call when it fires automatically?